# Does popup contents effect the page loading speed?

Tags: html, wordpress

I want to know whether contents in the popups like specifically images load during when the page loads or it loads when the popup is triggered and opened. I just want to know whether popup contents e.g images effect the page loading speed or not. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Popups will absolutely affect your page load speed. As far as images etc, it depends on how you choose to load them.

In most modern websites, there are many options for how you handle a pages assets. There's preload, HTTP/2, Lazyload, etc.

Either way, it will add server requests, javascript, and content. So even if you were to for instance, Lazy Load images, it will still increase your load.